# WPF: Proper configuration for Window with a child UserControl (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I am trying to properly accomplish the following. I have a UserControl (ProgramView). It has a viewmodel (ProgramViewViewModel). ProgramView is consumed as a child control within a Window (ProgramWindow). ProgramWindow has a public property ProgramId, so the consumer of the window can specify the desired Program (data entity) to show. ProgramView has a property ProgramId, as it's primary job is to display this data. ProgramWindow is little more than a wrapper window for this user control.

ProgramViewViewModel also has a property ProgramId. Changes to this property drive out the operation of the view model, which are surfaced out of the view model using other properties, which ProgramView can bind to.

I am trying to hide the operation of the view model from the consumer of the ProgramView and ProgramWindow.

This ProgramId should be bound through all of these layers. Changes to ProgramWindow.ProgramId should flow to ProgramView.ProgramId and then to ProgramViewViewModel.ProgramId. I cannot figure out how to properly implement this.

My current approach is to surface ProgramId in all three classes as a DP. Within the Window, I would imagine ProgramView being instantiated thusly:

```
<local:ProgramView ProgramId="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ProgramWindow}}, Path=ProgramId}" />
```

This appears to actually work. Within ProgramView, I do obtain changed events for the property, and they do appear to have the correct value. FindAncestor seems to operate properly.

How then should I synchronize the ProgramViewViewModel.ProgramId property? I see two ways. One way would be to set a Binding on the ProgramViewViewModel instance itself, to also use FindAncestor, and find the ProgramId on the ProgramViewViewModel This has two downsides. It requires ProgramViewViewModel to surface ProgramId as a dependency property. I'd rather like to avoid this, but it might be acceptable. Either way, I cannot accomplish it in XAML.

```
<local:View.DataContext>
    <local:ProgramViewViewModel
        ProgramId="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ProgramView}}, Path=ProgramId}" />
</local:View.DataContext>
```

This does not work. It appears that I cannot introduce a binding expression within the instantiation of the instance. FindAncestor reports that it cannot find ProgramView. My theory here is that the instance is outside of the logical tree, and thus cannot traverse to it's parent.

The second option, which makes more sense, is to bind the ProgramView.ProgramId property to "ProgramId" (in the DataContext). I cannot accomplish this because I cannot figure out how to specify a binding expression on a property defined in the code-behind.  is required in the XAML, but the type ProgramId exists on is actually . I cannot figure out how to specify this property.

If I manually (in code-behind of ProgramView) create a Binding instance and call SetBinding(ProgramIdProperty, binding), the value no longer flows into the View itself. I believe this is because I just replaced the binding on ProgramView.ProgramId, which was previously set by ProgramWindow. One binding per-property?

My remaining ideas are to provide TWO ProgramId properties in ProgramView. One bound to the DataContext, the other publicly available to be bound by the consumer (ProgramWindow), and then write OnValueChanged handlers that synchronize the two. This feels like a hack. The other is to manually watch for changes on ProgramView.ProgramId and ProgramView.DataContext within the code-behind of ProgramView, and propagate the value myself. Neither of these ideas feel ideal.

I'm looking for other suggestions.

Comment: Using the second ProgramIdProxy property works. I just don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Your description seems detailed but I'm having trouble understanding why you need to implement this design. I can't help but think DRY.

If you need to expose a dependency property in two such-related view models, I would suggest that you make the child view model (for the user control view) a property of the first (for the program window view).  Something like:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public ProgramViewModel ChildViewModel { get; private set; }

}

public class ProgramViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   private int _ProgramId;

   public int ProgramId
   {
      get { return _ProgramId; }
      set
      {
         if (value != _ProgramId)
         {
             // set and raise propery changed notification
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The MainView can get the property using ChildViewModel.ProgramId (data context set to MainViewModel). The ProgramView accesses it by ProgramId (data context set to MainViewModel.ChildViewModel).